# How to get the deleted docs that remote main solr server already deleted but still exist in local solr server

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am trying to implement the following function:

I have a main central solr server which contains all docs from all users.
In each client, I want to create a local cache of his/her docs(so if there is no internet connection, user can still search his/her local cache): first import the index of the user's doc created or changed in last 2 weeks(for example), then every day, at midnight get the index of the docs created, changed or deleted by that user during this period and import the change to local cache.

I use http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#SolrEntityProcessor
1. at first, use /dataimport&query=+from:jeffery +last_modified:[${last_2weeks_ago} TO NOW] to import index created/changed by this user in last 2 weeks.
2.  for the delta import, to check in the index created or changed(not including) deleted, I use /dataimport&query=+from:jeffery +last_modified:[${dataimporter.request.last_index_time} TO NOW]&clean=false.

But the difficult part is how to get the index of the docs that were deleted in the last day.
I found some ways to do this, but it's not efficient at all.

Solution 1 - not efficient.
1.  Read all ids(Only Load ID) in the local cache – named as ${local_ids}
2.  Read all ids in the remote central server  between ${first_index_time} and ${last_index_time} – named as ${ids_still_exist_in_remote_server}
3.  The deleted ids would be = ${local_ids}-${ids_still_exist _in_remote_server}

This can be optimized by only fetch N(for example 10000) ids from local cache server and remote solr server each time, then computes the difference in a loop until there is no id left in local and remote server.

Solution2:

In remote central solr server, when a doc is deleted, add an record like {docid, deletedate}(maybe some other information such as author) into solr server.
When run delta-import, make a query to get the deleted ids between ${last_index_time} to NOW.

Not know how to implement this yet, but I think this is implementable.
But this will slow the delete operation in remote central solr server and will keep record about deleted docs unnecessary in remote server. (although we can use a thread to delete old index about deleted docs)

Are there any other better ways to do this in solr?
Thanks very much for your help and advice :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Solr replication](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication) to replicate the Contents from the Remote server to the Local Server on periodic basis or make it event based (on commit or optimize).
You need not keep track of the updates.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jayendra. But seems I can't use Solr replication, as I don't want to import all index to local cache, just index of docs owned by the client. -- I can do this by SolrEntityProcessor via query="from:jeffery". But I think Solr replication doesn't support to replicate index based on a query.